# How to unit test and mock a method that takes a file as a parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class CollectionObject which creates a ArrayList.

```
public class CollectionObject {

    private List<String> collectionObject;

    public CollectionObject() {
        collectionObject = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public List<String> getCollectionObject() {
        return collectionObject;
    }

    public void add(final String stringToWrite) throws VerifyException {
        collectionObject.add(stringToWrite);
    }
}
```

There is another class which takes in the class CollectionObject and uses it to write the contents of the file to the class CollectionObject.

```
public class ReaderFileWriterObjectService {

    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private CollectionObject collectionObject;
    private String line;

    public CollectionObject getCollectionObjectAfterWritingFromAFile(final File file)
            throws VerifyException, IOException {
        collectionObject = new CollectionObject();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            collectionObject.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return collectionObject;
    }
```

How to Test and Mock the method of the class ReaderFileWriterObjectService?

Comment: You cannot. A `File` is too much bound into the JDK so that testing it is very hard. Should you use JSR 203 however, the story would be very different...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me complement on [@LouisWasserman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33743696/1093528).

You just cannot test APIs which rely on `java.io.File`; this class cannot be reliably unit tested (even though it is not even `final` at the JDK level).

But this is not the case with the new filesystem API, which appeared with Java 7.

Also known as JSR 203, this API provides a unified API to any storage medium providing "filesystem objects".

Short story:

- a "filesystem object" is materialized by a Path in this API;
- any JDK implementing JSR 203 (ie, any Java 7+ version) supports this API;
- to get a Path from a resource on the *default* `FileSystem`, you can use `Paths.get()`;
- but you are not limited to that.

In short, in your API *and* test case, you should use `Path`, not `File`. And if you want to test anything related to some filesystem resource, use the JDK's `Files` class to test `Path` instances.

And you *can* create `FileSystem`s out of your main, disk based, file system. Recommendation: use [this](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem).

Comment: Using `Path` carries other advantages too, it gives you a much cleaner separation of concerns and a lot of the functionality you need to fiddle around with (or use a 3rd party library) `File` comes out of the box.

Comment: @biziclop not sure what you meant, but I did use this API to implement `FileSystem`s over something else than the local disk (example [here](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-dropbox)), so the complexity of implementing this API doesn't elude me either...

Answer (score 2):

I am doing the same thing, And the following idea is working,
I hope this will work for u too,

```
 @InjectMocks
 private CollectionObject collectionObject;

@Test
public void getCollectionObjectAfterWritingFromAFile() throws Exception {
    CollectionObject  expectedObject =new CollectionObject();
    List<String> expectedList=new ArrayList<String>();
    expectedList.add("100");

    CollectionObject  resultObject =new CollectionObject();

    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new StringReader("100"));
    PowerMockito.mock(BufferedReader.class);
    PowerMockito.mock(FileReader.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(FileReader.class).withArguments("test10.csv").thenReturn(null);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(BufferedReader.class).withArguments(null).thenReturn(reader);
    resultObject=collectionObject.getCollectionObjectAfterWritingFromAFile( "test10.csv");
    assertEquals(expectedObject ,resultObject );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JUnit's [TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) for creating a file and copy the contents from a resource to it.

```
public YourText {
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test
  public void checkSomething() throws Exception {
    InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/your/resource");
    File file = folder.newFile();
    Files.copy(resource, file);
    ReaderFileWriterObjectService service = ...
    CollectionObject collection = service
        .getCollectionObjectAfterWritingFromAFile(file);
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  You're pretty much out of luck.  A better design would accept a Java 7 `java.nio.file.FileSystem` and a `Path` that could be swapped out for a test implementation, e.g. https://github.com/google/jimfs.

Comment: Well, jimfs is not really there for unit testing; [memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem) is a much safer bet here

Comment: @fge [are you sure about that](https://plus.google.com/+googleguava/posts/a3idqfdnpzC)?

Comment: Pretty much so, yes. Last time I checked, jimfs didn't even implement POSIX permissions correctly, for one...

Comment: It doesn't look like the OP needs anything along those lines; they just need a pretty simple filesystem...

Comment: Even so, why promote an in-memory implementation which is inferior? I stand by my word: memoryfilesystem is way ahead of jimfs for testing purposes.

Comment: @fge The crucial thing from the question's perspective is that it isn't possible with `File`, only with one of these alternatives. Which implementation to choose is useful to know too but is of secondary importance.

Comment: @biziclop I respectfully disagree. Day in, day out, we _all_ work with files. And since Java 7 we have a fully testable API for that: why not use it? Unfortunately, even nowadays, awareness of JSR 203 is very low.

Comment: @fge I may have phrased that wrong. What I meant to say was that the actual `FileSystem` implementation chosen is less relevant (and can change with time) than the fact that JSR 203 should be the basis of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, at first lets consider what do u want to test? If it is unit test then u dont want to test integrations like communications with filesystem, you have to test your own logic and your logic is something like:
1) Read next line from file using file system integration
2) add this line into my object

The second step you should not test because this method is too easy to break. The first step you can't test cause it performs integrations call. So i don't think that here u need a unit test

But if your logic will be more complicated, then you can introduce interface wrapper and mock it in your test:

```
public interface FileWrapper{
  public String readLine();
  public void close();
}
public class FileWrapperImpl implements FileWrapper{
  private File file;
  private BufferedReader reader;

  public FileWrapperImpl (File file){
     this.file = file;
     this.reader= ...
  }

  public String readLine(){
    return reader.nextLine();
  }
}
```

And then your ReaderFileWriterObjectService:

```
 public CollectionObject getCollectionObjectAfterWritingFromAFile(FileWrapper wrapper)
        CollectionObject  collectionObject = new CollectionObject();
        while ((line = wrapper.readLine()) != null) {
            collectionObject.add(line);
        }
        wrapper.close();
        return collectionObject;
    }
```

And now you can easily mock FileWrapper for test and pass it to your service

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing the API to accept Reader or BufferedReader - those can be mocked. Hide the dependency on file with a factory.